# How to repeat CommandButton1 execution until the condition is met?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I have a Excel VBA code executed by CommandButton1_Click. Following are conditions I have inserted at the end of my VBA code.

```
If Range("D1").Value < 362 Then
    Range("C1").Value = Range("C1").Value + 7
    Range("D1").Value = Range("D1").Value + 7   
Else
    Range("C1").Value = Range("F2").Value
    Range("D1").Value = 0    
End If
```

I want to repeat CommandButton1_Click action until Range("D1").Value is turned to Zero again. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would need wrap your entire body of `CommandButton1_Click` method in a `Do While ... Loop`.

So transform:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    'body
End Sub
```

to

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Do While Range("D1").Value <> 0
        'body
    Loop
End Sub
```

Or you could be more elegant:

```
Sub SomeSub()
    'your CommandButton1_Click current body
End Sub

Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Do While Range("D1").Value <> 0
        SomeSub
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

as per your own words

```
Do Until Range("D1").Value = 0
    If Range("D1").Value < 362 Then

        Range("C1").Value = Range("C1").Value + 7
        Range("D1").Value = Range("D1").Value + 7

    Else
        Range("C1").Value = Range("F2").Value
        Range("D1").Value = 0        
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: I would add a `DoEvents` statement to avoid locking down the workbook in case user interaction needed.

Comment: It seems not working. I have written this code above END SUB. Please help

Comment: @S.K.Baloch Make a new sub, copy the above code into it and call the new sub from the `CommandButton1_Click()`.